# Externalise common functions in various react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In different `components` where I use the same functions when it comes to styling or something else. Some of these functions use `this.setState({...});` I want to collect all these functions in a common place, so when rewriting them I don't have to rewrite them in all the components, but only on one file. However, I do not know how to write the `this.setState({...});` in the functions without loosing its context. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean exporting one function and call this function in various components while remaining the scope of `this`

MyExportedFunctions.js:

```
export function handleChange(value, {target: {name, type}}) {
    this.setState({[name]: value}, () => console.log(this.state));
}
```

MyComponent.js:

```
  import {handleChange} from "./MyExportedFunctions";

        class MyComponent extends Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.handleChange = handleChange.bind(this);

                this.state = {

                };
            }
            ...
     }
```

Did you mean something like this?

Comment: `this.setState({[name]: value},` wont set the state in the component you use the function in.

Comment: @Stophface It does though (I have dozens of exported functions in dozens of different files and they all work like charm). Have you tried printing the state to your console or provide what you already tried?

Comment: @Stophface how do you call the exported function? You call them like `this.exportedFunction` ?

Comment: you bind the context in the constructor, and then you call it in the component via `this.exportedFunction`?

Comment: Yes, you bind in once in the constructor (or whatever) and call it with `this` otherwise you loose the scope in the external function.

Comment: be carefull don't forget the import. watch his code

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks very much for posting.