# React-toolbox Tabs don't get rendered when code is imported from another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-toolbox

I am using [react-toolbox Tabs](http://react-toolbox.com/#/components/tabs) and they don't get rendered if I extract them into a separate file, but they render if the code is extracted in the same file. I cannot figure out the reason why that happens. For example:

```
function programDayTab({id, name, startTime}) {
    return (
        <Tab key={id} label={name}>
            <small>Start date: {new Date(startTime).toDateString()}</small>
            <small>Start time: {new Date(startTime).toTimeString()}</small>
        </Tab>
    );
}

function programDayTabs(days) {
    return days ? days.map(day => programDayTab(day)) : "";
}
....
    render() {
        const days = this.props.days;
        return (
            <Tabs index={this.state.selectedTabIndex} onChange={this.handleTabChange} fixed theme={theme}>
                {programDayTabs(days)}
            </Tabs>
        );
    }
```

If the two functions stay in the same file, everything works just fine. If I extract them in a separate JS file and import them into the React component file, then the tabs won't render, and I see no errors in the console. Any ideas why that might happen? Thanks!

Comment: Did you export the functions in the separate file and bound it to you component. Have you tried to `console.log()` in the functions? Are they called? Did you do something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675191/externalise-common-functions-in-various-react-components/45675589#45675589

Comment: @Nocebo I did export them, not sure what you mean by "bounding it to my component". The functions do get called, I see logs if I put them there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We worked out on Discord, the problem was (not shown in the original question):

```
import { Tab } from "react-toolbox/lib/tabs/Tab";
```

Instead of either of these correct forms:

```
import { Tab } from "react-toolbox";
```

or

```
import Tab from "react-toolbox/lib/tabs/Tab";
```