# Move function in React from component to referenced library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and I'm not sure how to setup this pattern. It could be something really easy I'm just missing.

I have a main component that controls state. It has all of the functions to update state and passes these down to child components via props. I've simplified the code to focus on one of these functions.

Here's the component now, all works as it should:

**ManageMenu.js**

```
import React from 'react'

class ManageMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.toggleEditing = this.toggleEditing.bind(this)

    // Set initial state
    this.state = {
      menuSections: []
    }
  }

  toggleEditing(id) {
    const menuSections = this.state.menuSections

    menuSections.map(key => (key.id === id ? key.details.editing = id : ''))

    this.setState({ menuSections })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}

export default ManageMenu
```

The toggleEditing is passed via props to a child component that uses it to render an editing form if the edit button is clicked.

I have about 10 of these different functions in this component and what I would like to do is move them to an external `lib/methods.js` file and then reference them. Below is the code I would like to have, or something similar, but React doesn't like what I'm doing. Throws a syntax error:

```
Failed to compile.
Error in ./src/components/ManageMenu.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token
toggleEditing(id, menuSectionId, this.state, this)
```

---

Here is what I would like to do...

**lib/methods.js**

```
const toggleEditing = function(id, state, that) {
  const menuSections = state.menuSections

  menuSections.map(key => (key.id === id ? key.details.editing = id : ''))

  that.setState({ menuSections })
}

module.exports = {
  toggleEditing
}
```

And then in my component:

**ManageMenu.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { toggleEditing } from '../lib/methods'

class ManageMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    // Set initial state
    this.state = {
      menuSections: []
    }
  }

  toggleEditing(id, this.state, this)

  render() {
    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}

export default ManageMenu
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to externalize functions? If so check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675191/externalise-common-functions-in-various-react-components/45675589#45675589

Comment: Yep, that's it! Worked perfectly, thanks. I'll update this with an answer that fixes my code based on that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Nocebo, the answer on how to externalize functions is here:
[Externalise common functions in various react components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675191/externalise-common-functions-in-various-react-components/45675589#45675589)

In my particular situation,

1. I need to remove the “floating” `toggleEditing(id, this.state, this)` call in the middle of nowhere. **Update:** This error happens “because it is invoking a method within a class definition.” (see [Pineda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2902660/pineda)’s [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882498/move-function-in-react-from-component-to-referenced-library/45882717?noredirect=1#comment78724047_45882717))
2. Remove the leading `this.` on the right side of the `this.toggleEditing` statement in `constructor()`
3. Update the function in `lib/methods.js` to remove the `state` and `that` variables since its bound to `this` in the `constructor()`

See updated code below.

**ManageMenu.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { toggleEditing } from '../lib/methods'

class ManageMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.toggleEditing = toggleEditing.bind(this)

    // Set initial state
    this.state = {
      menuSections: []
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}

export default ManageMenu
```

**lib/methods.js**

```
const toggleEditing = function(id) {
  const menuSections = this.state.menuSections

  menuSections.map(key => (key.id === id ? key.details.editing = id : ''))

  this.setState({ menuSections })
}

module.exports = {
  toggleEditing
}
```

Comment: It'd be good if you expand point (1) to include the issue of leaving that line in causes the error, i.e. it it because it is invoking a method within a class definition.

Answer (score 1):

You're error arises because you are invoking `toggleEditing` in your ManageMenu.js class definition rather than *defining* a function.

You can achive what you want by setting a local class member `this.toggleEditing` to the bound function returned by the `.bind` method and do so within the constructor:

```
import React from 'react'
import { toggleEditing } from '../lib/methods'

class ManageMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()    
    this.state = {
      menuSections: []
    }

    // bind external function to local instance here here
    this.toggleEditing = toggleEditing.bind(this);
  }

  // don't invoke it here, bind it in constructor
  //toggleEditing(id, this.state, this)

  render() {
    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}

export default ManageMenu
```